# Writing PHP in Notepad++, and using Spanish letters?

Tags: php, encoding, internationalization, character-encoding, notepad++

I don't get it - what encoding should I use? I've been using ANSI, but when I save the document, Spanish letters are converted to illegible markings.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, for almost any document, you should use UTF-8 without a BOM. (The exception is documents targeting most Asian countries which are usually more efficiently stored in UTF-16).

You also need to make sure that:

- it doesn't get transcoded en-route
- any database the data is stored in is UTF-8 aware
- any `<meta>` element in an HTML document that states an encoding states the correct encoding. (If the document is intended for viewing from a file system instead of over HTTP then add such an element)
- the HTTP headers state that the document is UTF-8

Answer (score 3):

you should use `UTF-8 without BOM`